# How to find the POD of a particular virtual guest using SoftLayer API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How to find the POD of a particular virtual guest using SL API. I tried using the SoftLayer_Hardware_Router but was not successful in fetching the information.

Thanks,
Mala

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this post:

[Finding VSi's or Bare metals in certain pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638360/finding-vsis-or-bare-metals-in-certain-pods)

Let me know if that help you

Regards

Comment: I was able to get it from frontendRouters[hostname]. Thank You